# Linq to linq.js translation with value assignation

Tags: c#, linq, linq.js

I am trying to assign a value with a linq.js expresion. The linq lamba expresion would be like this:

```
List<SearchSpaceRoom> roomsAvailable = Spaces.Select(s => 
   { 
       s.Available = s.Rooms.Where(r => r.RoomTypeRanges.Any(t => t.Type.ToString() == "Theatre" && t.Min <= 101 && t.Max >= 200)).Count(); 
       return s; 
   })
   .ToList();
```

But I cannot find the way to do this to work with linq.js. The idea is to have something like this:

```
var data = eval($('#SpaceJson').val());
var results = $.Enumerable.From(data).ToArray();
var layout = 'Theatre';
var minDelegates = '101';
var maxDelegates = '200';

results = $.Enumerable.From(results)
   .Select('{$.Available = $.Rooms.Where($.RoomTypeRanges.Any($.Type == \'' + layout + '\' && $.Min <= \'' + parseInt(minDelegates) + '\' && t.Max >= \'' + parseInt(maxDelegates) + '\')).Count(); return $; }').ToArray();
```

Is this possible, can anyone suggest me the best approach to do this?

If you need more information about the expression:
it is to assign the amount of rooms that meets the requirements of Min and Max people for a certain layout (Classroom, Theatre) for each space.
The basic structure is like:

1. One space contains Rooms
2. One Room contains the different layouts
3. A layout contains the max an min people

I can provide all the data structure if you need but I believe that will confuse more than help.

Thanks!

EDIT: I add the classes here

```
public class SearchSpaceViewModel
{
    public List<SearchSpaceRoom> Spaces { get; set; }
    public string RoomsJson { get; set; }
}

public class SearchSpaceRoom
{
    public List<RoomItem> Rooms { get; set; }
    public int Available { get; set; }
    .
    .
    .
}

public class RoomItem
{
    public List<RoomTypeRange> RoomTypeRanges { get; set; }
    .
    .
    .

}

public class RoomTypeRange
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public int Max { get; set; }
    public int Min { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to close this, I managed to do it using a mix of JQuery and linq.js:

```
 function ParseJson() {
        var data = eval($('#RoomsJson').val());
        var results = $.Enumerable.From(data).ToArray();
        var layout = 'Theatre';
        var intMin = 101;
        var intMax = 200;

        $.each(results, function (i, space) {
            var count = 0;
            $.each(space.Rooms, function (j, room) {
                if ($.Enumerable.From(room.RoomTypeRanges).Any('$.Type == \'' + layout + '\' && $.Min <= ' + intMin + ' && $.Max >= ' + intMax)) {
                    count++;
                }
            });
            space.Available = count;
        });

        return results;
    }
```

I am sure that there are more elegant solutions but it seems to work fine.